# background-position not behaving consistently across browsers, specifically Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, background-image

I'm working on a site where we're using the `background-image: url('')` CSS property.

It works well, but it seems that `background-position` is calculated differently in Firefox than in Safari/Chrome.

In my code (below) the image to the right (`right-floater` class) doesn't seem to render the same. Open up the fiddle in both Firefox & Chrome to see what I'm talking about - in Firefox the positioning of the background image is much lower than in Chrome/Safari.

I'm using `background-position: 50% 0%;` which works well in Chrome/Safari but with Firefox it seems that `background-position: 50% 100%` gives the same results while 50% 0% end up making the site look pretty bad in FF.

I've tried to play around with a lot of the elements and it seems like this is the culprit...
What is going wrong?

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.left-floater {
  height: calc(100vh - 75px);
  width: 40vw;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2296/3395/files/TOMO-Website-R3-06.svg?10381558204658209910);
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right-floater {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2296/3395/t/2/assets/Sculpture.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 54vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 75px);
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: auto 100vh;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-wrap">
  <div class="left-floater"></div>
  <div class="right-floater"></div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vahg9eo/4/)

Comment: Sorry mate looks identical for me in Chrome / FF.

Comment: Weird, even in a large window? I wonder what's going on here.....

Comment: Confirmed this with another computer - it is identical. My Firefox has to be the culprit, still don't understand why but I'll post an answer if I find out.

Comment: Maybe check the CSS "rules" and "computed" styles in Firefox and see if something is being set from an unexpected source, or if the styles differ between your Firefox and Chrome browsers.